# How to connect to one drive using one drive connector in Azure Logics App

Tags: python, azure, cloud, azure-logic-apps, onedrive

I'm Trying to connect to OneDrive using Logic App . I have created a Trigger: when file is created in one drive
. But I don't know in the folder what value to give , it is also not opening the one drive , allowing me to manual navigate to the desire folder .

If simpling giving the name of the folder like "/Documents" Then its giving 404 error - Invalid Object .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click on the folder picker that will list all the folders available in OneDrive.
[image]

If the folders are not getting listed, it means connection is not authenticated correctly. You can try to create a new API connection and share the error message if any.